# Differences between PUSH eax and mov [esp], eax?

Tags: assembly, x86

What is the difference between the two lines

```
push eax

mov [esp], eax
```

Doesn't push eax on to the stack (where esp is pointing to just as mov [esp], eax does?)

Comment: "push" will automatically bump the value of "esp" (your stack pointer). The "mov" won't.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"push" will automatically bump the value of "esp" (your stack pointer). The "mov" won't. So i if you wanted to put multiple items on the stack, with `push`, you just do:

```
push eax
push ebx
...
```

With `mov`, to get the same results, you'd have:

```
sub  esp,4
mov  [esp], eax
sub  esp,4
mov  [esp], ebx
...
```

And the nice thing about `push` is that there is the reverse operation, `pop` which allows you to pull things back off in reverse order. Which is, of course, what a stack is all about. :)

Comment: Ah ok, but wouldn't it be sub esp, 4 sense the stack goes to lower values?

Comment: @Zimm3r yes in the case of x86 (correction made). In some architectures it is possible to have a stack which "grows up" instead of down. But x86 is down. :)

Comment: Ah ok thanks for a second I was a bit worried I'd been doing it wrong.

Comment: @Zimm3r and note that doing it "manually" the subtract comes first, then the move. The stack pointer always points to the last thing pushed.

Comment: Is there any reason why the compiler would use `sub esp, 4 ` and `mov dword ptr ss:[esp],2E` instead of `PUSH 2E` (6A2E, 2 byte vs 10 byte)? I see it happening in my program, not sure if there is any purpose I am missing.

Comment: @Zackline I don't think you're missing anything. The operation serves the same purpose functionally. In the case of `sub esp, 4`, etc, the `sub esp, 4` "reserves" the stack space and then the subsequent `mov` uses that space.